# Amazon AWS iOS SDK anonymous access for public S3 object

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am confused on how to access a public file on my S3 account with the SDK for iOS. I was able to do this in my Android version with the following code.

```
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();
GetObjectMetadataRequest metadataRequest = new GetObjectMetadataRequest(/* my bucket/object stuff */);
ObjectMetadata metadata = client.getObjectMetadata(metadataRequest);
/* Some checking on the metadata */
S3Object xml = client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(/* my bucket/object stuff */));
S3ObjectInputStream xmlData = xml.getObjectContent();
/* Use the data of the object */
```

Though looking at the source code of the S3 Library for iOS it seems like it's mandatory for having an access key and private key otherwise it would fail in the HMAC routine. Does anyone have any advice for me on this?

Thanks,

Andrew Querol

Answer (score 0):

I just switched to another networking library. I ended up using MKNetworkKit.